# how to update data in SQL from Gridview moving from one Row to another in ASP,C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view as below,
[GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i43sR.png)

I want to update table based on the text entered in the text box, when the focus shifted to next row. How can I achieve that?

I have done the coding in page index changing, I'm new to web programming bit confused how to achieve that using C# in ASP.

Below is the code I've written for page index changing..

**ASP**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GVItems" runat="server"
                            CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" GridLines="None"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GVItems_PageIndexChanging" OnRowEditing="GVItems_RowEditing" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GVItems_SelectedIndexChanging">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" />
                            <Columns>
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="UNIQ" HeaderText="UNIQ"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="store" HeaderText="STORE" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="MQty" HeaderText="Modified Qty" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit MQty" >
                                    <ItemTemplate >
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpdatedQty" runat="server" Text="" Width="40" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <RowStyle CssClass="cursor-pointer" />
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="pagination-ys" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

**C#**

```
protected void GVItems_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateRecvQty();
        GVItems.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
private void UpdateRecvQty()
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GVItems.Rows)
        {
            if (((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtUpdatedQty")).Text != "")
            {
                uniqID = row.Cells[0].Text;
                qty = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtUpdatedQty")).Text;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();

                string query = "UPDATE [dbo].[Tbl_Order]  SET MQty = @qty where UNIQU=@uniqID";
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqID", uniqID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the textChanged event of the textbox and update the value every time the user edits the textbox instead of looping at the end?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is there any way to update the same on move down to next row?

Comment: This should automatically happen if when the user changes the text and then presses tab or moves away from the textbox. Unless I am not understanding what you mean by move to the next row?